# How to scrape all the search results using Selenium webdriver and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to scrape all CRD# from the search result from this site https://brokercheck.finra.org/search/genericsearch/list

(You'll need to redo the search when you click on the link, just type some random stuff for the `Individual` search)

[image]

I'm using `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` to target all CRD numbers on each result page. However, I've been playing around with the paths for a while but the webdriver still can't pick up the CRDs from the site.

I currently have (in Python)

```
crds = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//md-list-item/div/div/div/div/div/bc-bio-geo-section/div/div/div/div/div/span")
```

But the result is always empty.

Comment: They have similar span classes of spacerright ng-binding. driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class = 'spacerright ng-binding']")); Then loop and print .getText() maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print all the `CRD#` from the search results within the website https://brokercheck.finra.org/search/genericsearch/grid using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.ng-binding[ng-bind-html='vm.item.id']")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *text*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[starts-with(., 'CRD')]//following-sibling::span[1]")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **`.find_elements_by_css_selector`** like this:

```
crds = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[ng-bind-html='vm.item.id']")
```