# Scrape conditional results Python Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

This is a follow up from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61882661/how-to-scrape-all-the-search-results-using-selenium-webdriver-and-python) I had. Basically, I'm trying to scrape all CRD# from the search result from this site https://brokercheck.finra.org/search/genericsearch/list

(You'll need to redo the search when you click on the link, just type some random stuff for the `Individual` search)

I'm trying to scrape the `Disclosure` to get `Yes` or `No`, but this box uses an `ng-if` to display `Yes` or `No`, or for some rows it won't even display it.

[image]

I'm using the `CSS_SELECTOR` to select the text of that `div`. However, the content of the `ng-if` is different

```
# No
print([disclosure.get_attribute("innerHTML") for disclosure in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ng-scope[ng-if='!vm.item.hasDisclosures() && vm.item.hasDisclosureFlag()'")))])

# Yes
print([disclosure.get_attribute("innerHTML") for disclosure in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ng-scope[ng-if='vm.item.hasDisclosures()'")))])
```

How do I programmatically handle this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want in such cases is Xpath which are dependent on your text.

first you want to get the `Disclosures` div and then the div next to it

```
//div[@class='flipper']//md-card-content/div/div//*[contains(., "Disclosures")]
```

And then to get the next div

```
//div[@class='flipper']//md-card-content/div/div//*[contains(., "Disclosures")]/following-sibling::div[1]/div
```

Then you can get the div. So basically when you are looping through each of the flipper card you should run something find element as `.//md-card-content/div/div//*[contains(., "Disclosures")]
/following-sibling::div[1]/div` to find the value of disclosure in the card. If the element is not there, that means no disclosure was specified

Answer (score 1):

To print all the *Disclosure* values i.e. `Yes` or `No` from the search results within the website https://brokercheck.finra.org/search/genericsearch/grid using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `hasDisclosures()`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ng-scope[ng-if*='hasDisclosures']")))])
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `hasDisclosureFlag()`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ng-scope[ng-if*='hasDisclosureFlag']")))])
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`, `hasDisclosures()` and `hasDisclosureFlag()`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ng-scope[ng-if*='hasDisclosures'][ng-if*='hasDisclosureFlag']")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```